How to apply numpy's Poisson function on a Polars column and find the most frequent result?
I'm trying to work with the Polars library in Python and need to use numpy's poisson function on each value of a column. Specifically, I want to generate multiple samples (e.g., 1000) for each value in the column and determine the most frequent sample (mode) for each row.
For example, given the following DataFrame:
import polars as pl  

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "HomeLambda": [1.5, 2.0, 3.2]
})

I want to:

Apply np.random.poisson(lam=HomeLambda, size=1000) for each row.
Count the occurrences of each value in the 1000 samples.
Find the value with the highest count (mode) for each row.

The expected result would look like this:
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────────┬──────────────┐
│ HomeLambda  │ PredictedHome│
│ ---         │ ---          │
│ f64         │ i64          │
├─────────────┼──────────────┤
│ 1.5         │ 1            │
│ 2.0         │ 2            │
│ 3.2         │ 3            │
└─────────────┴──────────────┘

How can I achieve this efficiently in Polars?
My initial attempt looked something like this, but I can't figure out how to incorporate np.random.poisson into the Polars workflow:
lambda_table.with_columns(
    pl.Series(rng.poisson(lam=pl.col("HomeLambda"), size=1000)).value_counts().top_k(k=1,by="count")['count'].item().alias("PredictedHome"),
)

Any suggestions or best practices for integrating numpy functions with Polars and performing this kind of row-wise operation?

Would rng.poisson([1.5, 2.0, 3.2], size=(1000, 3)).T give the same result as 3 separate poisson calls? Failing that, it seems you'd need to fallback to map_elements as poisson does not appear to be a ufunc.
